# CSS selector not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hey guys, thanks in advance for any help or input. I am having trouble understanding CSS selectors and i have read the docs..

I am trying to refer to the UL with the id dropdown in my stylesheet. I was under the assumption that i was able to refer to any elements like:

```
#dropdown ul  
{
}
```

This method however does not seem to work :s.. Am i misunderstanding CSS selectors? The elements in my actual code are nested deeper than this structure but i presume the principle is the same?

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li class="sub"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>

      <!-- Sub Menu -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- End Submenu -->

    </li>
  </ul>

</div>


/* Dropdown Menu */
#dropdown ul 
{
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#dropdown ul li 
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#dropdown li ul 
{
   display: none; 
}

#dropdown ul li a 
{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background: #2C5463;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#dropdown ul li a:hover 
{ 
   background: #617F8A; 
}

#dropdown li:hover ul 
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

#dropdown li:hover li 
{
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#dropdown li:hover a 
{ 
   background: #617F8A; 
}

#dropdown li:hover li a:hover 
{ 
   background: #95A9B1; 
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? It works perfectly. You can possibly share your stylesheet and tell which attribute is failing.

Comment: Added the css that generates the dropdown

Comment: Kangkan, Lee wants to select `#dropdown` but is currently selecting `ul #dropdown`, which is a completely different selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ul#dropdown
{
}
```

This will select the ul element with ID dropdown.

With

```
#dropdown ul
```

you are trying to locate a ul element within an element with id dropdown. This will select *all* ul elements inside the #dropdown ul, however many levels deep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I've added what you have suggested to my CSS file however it didnt work. I have edited the original post to show the CSS that should style the dropdown.

Comment: The CSS in your update doesn't match what Mario has suggested.

Comment: Marios solution works great for the ul element.. However the following line:

li a            
{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background: #2C5463;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

to: 

ul#dropdown li a it seems to break

Comment: In what way does it break? It is selecting something different - `li a` selects all a elements inside any li elements, `ul#dropdown li a` selects all a elements inside any li elements inside the ul#dropdown element.

Comment: ul#dropdown li a the style doesnt seem to be applied any longer.. Sorry im not explaining this very well..

Comment: Do you mean that changing `#dropdown ul li a` to `ul#dropdown li a` stops the style from being applied? Do you have another style that applies to the a tags that you're not showing in your example? Try `ul#dropdown ul li a`

Answer (score 1):

edit: it's right as mario wrote.

edit2: im sorry for being 5seconds too slow, i just wanted to help. For completition of my post:
`ul#dropdown` or `#dropdown`  is the right selection

Comment: Thanks for the help.. ul#dropdown works fine for the mian UL element.. The problem seems to exist changing the more complex selectors..

Comment: works finde for me -> http://jsbin.com/afufa3/
edit: ul#dropdown li a  works too.

Comment: Ahh ok that helped me.. #dropdown works fine.. i was trying with ul#dropdown

Answer (score 0):

`#dropdown ul` means "select any `ul` that is a direct or indirect child of `#dropdown`". That is not what you want, I think. Try `#dropdown` alone (you don't need to mention `ul` as IDs are exclusive, meaning you should only have one `#dropdown` in a page).